# Pull request closed, should I revert my change (or something else?)

Tags: git, github

I made a change/commit to a file on a branch specifically created for this purpose.  I submitted a pull request to GitHub, but as it turns out we found another way to do this and my PR was closed (no hard feelings.)

Now I'm wondering what to do on my local repo?  If I delete the branch the file change will still be there, will it not?  Should I revert the commit, or will that uglify the history in some way, since it was never integrated to our main branch?

Comment: the question is a bit vague - does the project have a reference branch like ``master``? was this feature branch of yours merged into ``master`` locally?

Comment: Hi,
We do have a reference branch (called 'develop' in our instance) and my feature branch was not merged into that reference branch locally-- I submitted my PR from my branch itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the branches (the one with the PR and the one that you merged the PR into) and then execute `git fetch`. Now you will have the same code as in the remote repo without your changes.